# Switching winForms and how to avoid white rectangles

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, refresh

i have to do an application with more forms: i first create and load the forms, after that i hide all, showing just one of them. 
With some buttons i switch between the forms by showing and hiding them with the relative functions 
`Show()` and `Hide()`
The problem is that when i show a form, all the controls for an instant begin some white rectangles, after that they were loaded correctly.

I've looked everywhere but i can't find any result.
How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: Setting this to true, can reduce the flickering
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I've used the property `DoubleBuffered` and the flickering is decreased about 50%, but it still remains a little bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding the properties `FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None`and  `DoubleBuffered = true` in the constructor of a new form created with the designer.
After that i've created an array of that type of form

Answer (score 0):

you mean many forms or these forms is all in one form?

I think you can use `Invalidate()`function in the Load function.

Comment: you can give me a example and I will fix it for you